# Android resources not found on some devices

Tags: android, resources, build, device

We have an application(with moderate amount of strings) which we translate to 27+ languages. We make 2 builds of the application. These 2 builds only differ in the name of the package. So basically we first do a build of our application with package name lets say `com.android.sad.app` and then another one  with package name `com.android.even.sadder.app`.
We had the chance to test our application on a great variety of Android devices and we have found out that on some devices like **Samsung ACE**, **Samsung Galaxy S** or **LG Optimus 2x** our application can't load/read the *resources* so even the application icon isn't shown and when the application is started it crashes with `android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException`. On other devices everything is working just fine.

We have found out  that if we *reduce* the overall amount of strings in the resources of the application, our application can successfully run on the above mentioned devices. However we do not think this is the real solution to our problem because the debug build with full strings in resources can be ran on the devices in question.

So my question would be does someone knows what can potentially cause this very strange behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error experimenting we have found out that the problem was with the **apk** package itself. In our build process we add some *files* to our application **apk** right after the build has finished but before signing and aligning the **apk** file. Originally we were extracting and repackaging the **apk** with our own tool (which is written in *Java* and thus using the Java implementation of **Zip**).

We have noticed that after repackaging the **apk** with our tool we were able to reduce the size of the **apk** to **half size** of the original **apk** created by the *Android build*. 
As we have found out this *repackaging* was the cause of our problem!

As our experiments have shown if the repacked **apk** was smaller then **~1.6 Mb**, all devices were able to read and work with the newly *repacked* **apk**. However if the size of the **apk** have exceeded **~1.6 Mb** the devices (and the emulator) mentioned in this post were not able to correctly read or work with the application **apk** .

I have been looking around for some specification on the **apk file format**(which is essentially jar), but I have found nothing that would explain this very odd behavior. So could somebody please clarify why is this strange behavior happening and what are the exact reasons?

*Note: from now on we are using the Android* **aapt** *tool to insert our files to the package, instead of the tool we have been using and the final apk can be read by all devices*

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume a lot here, but I would put money on it being related to the amount of strings. All of your strings will consume memory and maybe these target devices don't have enough available to your application. As for your package name differences, the shorter one will consume less bytes than the longer one of course.

I suggest that you reduce the amount of strings in use and see if that resolves your issues.